# Determine a Folder for Sent Items in Outlook and remember last selected folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a send-and-file option for Outlook 2016 and luckily I found this [Site](http://www.vboffice.net/en/developers/determine-folder-for-sent-items/?mnu=2&pub=6&cmd=showitem). However, because we have a lot of shared mailboxes my dialog box opens and defaults to the main account's inbox.

So far I couldn't find a way to make it remember the last selected folder in the folder picker. From the site I mentioned, we can only use to pick the folder manually because shared mailboxes are not read as an account by Outlook.

How do I add a script in VB to make it remember the last selected folder. If not then what another option we can accept is make the treeview expanded or just set another default folder. Thanks much.

Here's the code btw:

```
    Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    Cancel = Not SaveSentMail(Item)
  End If
End Sub

Private Function SaveSentMail(Item As Outlook.MailItem) As Boolean
  Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder

  If Item.DeleteAfterSubmit = False Then
    Set F = Application.Session.PickFolder
    If Not F Is Nothing Then
      Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = F
      SaveSentMail = True
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Just to add, the feature I'm working on is similar to Lotus Notes send-and-file option.

Comment: I think you could as well look at this from the opposite side. First set/identify the mailbox/account so you know the associated SentIems folder to use instead of going through Pickfolder.

Comment: Keep in mind that SaveSentMessageFolder can only be set to a folder in the same store where the item resides.

Comment: Is the pick folder always the same?

Answer (score 1):

The PickFolder method and the dialog that is displayed has no options and cannot be customized. The only other option is to use Redemption, which offers many customizations for selecting a folder.  See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOSelectFoldersDialog.htm.